# How to clone row in dynamic table MVC and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy, html-table, clone

I have Master - Details forms in MVC project, view page.
In details table I add value and dynamic created table with rows. 
Now I need to Clone/Copy any row if I have same values for 2,3,4 or more rows.

I add rows with jquery, and now how to implement  to Clone or Copy row included values of entered row and new ID of row?

Code of the table creating:

```
           var $row = $('<tr />');
            $row.append($('<td  style="text-align:left"/>').html(val.profilID));
            $row.append($('<td/>').html((val.pr_cena).toFixed(0) + " €"));
            $row.append($('<td align="center"/>').html(val.pr_msh));
            $row.append($('<td/>').html(val.pr_mv));
            $row.append($('<td/>').html(val.pr_krila));
            $row.append($('<td class="TotalPR"/>').html((val.Total1) + " €"));
            $row.append($('<td  style="text-align:left"/>').html(val.meID));
            $row.append($('<td class="TotalME"/>').html((val.me_cena).toFixed(0) + " €"));
            $row.append($('<td  style="text-align:left"/>').html(val.stID));
            $row.append($('<td class="TotalST"/>').html((val.st_cena) + " €"));
            $row.append($('<td class="Total"/> ').html((val.Total) + " €"));
            var $remove = $('<a href="#">Бриши</a>');
            $remove.click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                orderItems.splice(i, 1);
                GeneratedItemsTable();
            });
            $row.append($('<td/>').html($remove));
            $tbody.append($row);
            $row = $('<tr/>');
```

Comment: `$( ".hello" ).clone().appendTo( ".goodbye" );`

Comment: Hallo, maby stuped but i must ask you again, i`m new in this job, and i`m Juniot in MVC programming. i understand you , but if you can clearly to tell me how to implement.  Thank you a lot.

Comment: Since you haven't provide a working code snippet and it is too much work for us to write up code, I give you a tip, do a google search with `jquery clone` and you'll find a lot of links/samples how to do

Comment: Thank you, i solved but on another way. :) if any full solution good to know it. Thank you